# wysiwyg box only shows html

Tags: wysiwyg, distributions

I manage a small drupal (openAtrium) site at work that we use for project management. Last week the wysiwyg textbox used to edit content stopped working. By stopped working I mean html was displayed regardless of the setting chosen. At the time I was using tinyMCE although since this I have tried CKEditor and openwysiwyg to no avail. For some users this only only an irritation but for others, who relied on the wrodprocessor features of wysiwyg mode it's more of a show stopper.

I can't find any error messages or indeed any indication that something is wrong in drupal. In terms of browsers I do get one JS error which maybe related.

*Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select:[name="field_oa_section[und]"], select:[name="field_oa_space_type[und]"]*

All browsers I have tried (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Konqueror) are affected. Does anyone have any ideas? I can't find anyone else who has experienced similar problems.

Thanks.

Comment: does it work consistently for anyone (i.e. an Admin)?

Comment: No - all users experience the same regardless of user rights.

Comment: does the editor show, or is it showing just the plain text editor?  the JS error - what file is producing that error?

Comment: the editor just displays a text editor populated with the html. The JS file showing the error is jquery.min.js.

Comment: do you have jquery update running?  I know some of them have issues with later versions of jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be multiple required versions of jquery. A jquery manaement module solved the problem.

Comment: Hello, which module did you use? I'm having the same error, and no clue which module or solution to apply. Thank you in advance.